# How to handle event if window service killed

Tags: c++, windows, service

I have developed window service. I want to know how can I get notification if service is killed. Presently i am getting notification if service is stopped.

```
----service startup code---

inline void CServiceModule::Init(_ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* p, HINSTANCE h, UINT      nServiceNameID, const GUID* plibid)
{
    CComModule::Init(p, h, plibid);

    m_bService = TRUE;
    m_hInstance = h;

    if(m_szServiceName.size()==0)
    {
        string strServiceName = GetServiceName(); 
        m_szServiceName = strServiceName;
    }

    // set up the initial service status 
    m_hServiceStatus = NULL;
    m_status.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    m_status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    m_status.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN;
    m_status.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    m_status.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    m_status.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    m_status.dwWaitHint = 0;
}

 ---Handler----
 inline void CServiceModule::Handler(DWORD dwOpcode)
 {
     switch (dwOpcode)
     {
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
            SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING);
            PostThreadMessage(dwThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
            break;
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE:
            break;
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE:
            break;
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
            break;
  /*    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:

        break;*/
        default:
            LogEvent(_T("Bad service request"));
    }
}
```

I am getting notification `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` when service is stopped. Please suggest what handler should i used if service is killed.

Comment: you got request to stop - `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` and handle it. *if service is killed* - what you mean under this ? somebody terminate service process ? in this case service of course not get any notify

Answer (score 0):

If it's killed, it's killed. It ends. Immediately. You don't get any signals.

*However* recent windows versions will never just *kill* a process if you select that in the task manager. They will first send a close signal (as if you had pressed Alt-F4) to the app to give it a chance to close gracefully. The app will only be terminated if it does not shut down in a specified time span.

Comment: Services are isolated in Session 0. Task Manager and taskkill.exe can't enumerate windows of a Desktop in another Session, let alone send a `WM_CLOSE` window message or post a `WM_QUIT` thread message across Session boundaries. Anyway, modern services generally don't create windows (since they're run in a non-interactive WindowStation) or even have an attached console. `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` is the only way I know to gracefully end a service -- not necessarily the process.